# copying list to multidimensional list

Tags: python, list

I have a single dimension list 'dataList' containing 5 elements and a multi dimensional list 'multiList' with 20 rows and 5 columns.The data in the dataList is coming from serial communication. 
I am trying to do is to add dataList row by row in to multiList, if the limit of 20 rows exceeds the new row must replace the old rows i.e. 21st row should replace 1st row, 22nd should replace 2nd row.
I have attached the code.

```
multiList = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
[],[],[],[]]
row=20
col=4


def update():
    if getValues() == b'104'.decode('ascii'):
        for i in range(0, numPoints):
            dataList[i] = getValues()
        for x in range (row):
            for y in range (5):
                multiList[x].append(dataList[y])
        print(multiList)
```

Comment: Please remove anything from your code that isn't relevant to the question. I can't find which part of your code is your attempt at solving this problem. Also please describe what your code does wrong.

Comment: Now i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly... 
the column of dataList is fixed as 5. And When the 
update function is called once, one dataList comes in.

That python code should be....

```
multiList = [[0]*5]*20 # initialization (20, 5)
row=20
col=5
current_index = 0
dataList=[0]*5

def update():
    global current_index
    if getValues() == b'104'.decode('ascii'):
        for i in range(0, numPoints): # it seems that numPoints should be 'col'
            dataList[i] = getValues()

        multiList[current_index] = list(dataList)
        current_index = (current_index+1)%row

        print(multiList)
```